# ARC and CFRelease?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I'm slightly confused. Everywhere I've read, suggest that when using ARC, you still need to release core foundation objects which makes sense, ARC doesn't manage them. However, I've got a method which uses some CF methods/objects which I used `CFRelease` on, but that then caused the app to crash. Uncommenting my `CFRelease`s fixes the issue but then I'm assuming I've got a memory leak?

Could someone please explain which things need releasing and which don't, or anything else that's wrong with this code?

```
+ (NSString *) fileExtensionForMimeType:(NSString *)type
{
    CFStringRef mimeType = (__bridge CFStringRef)type;
    CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType, NULL);
    CFStringRef extension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);

    NSString *ext = (__bridge NSString *)extension;

    // CFRelease(mimeType);
    // CFRelease(uti);
    // CFRelease(extension);

    return ext;
}
```

The three commented out `CFRelease` calls fix the issue as mentioned, but I know it's wrong. What should I be doing?

Comment: what's wrong with the 3 commented commands. Just uncomment it is fine

Comment: When I uncomment them, my app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. Doing a trace in instruments points to this method and commenting those lines fixes it

Comment: You should only release uti & extension, but not mimeType because you are not increasing the reference count of mimeType. you are simply type casting it. Uncomment last to CFRelease and then let me know what happens

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't release `mimeType` because you don't own it. You didn't transfer ownership with the `__bridge` cast.

You should be releasing `uti` since you have created it.

You should also release `extension` since you created it as well, but that will likely cause issues with `ext`. Instead, transfer ownership to `ext`.

I'd suggest the following:

```
+ (NSString *) fileExtensionForMimeType:(NSString *)type {
    CFStringRef mimeType = (__bridge CFStringRef)type;
    CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType, NULL);
    CFStringRef extension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);

    NSString *ext = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)extension;

    // CFRelease(mimeType); // not owned
    if (uti) CFRelease(uti);
    // CFRelease(extension); // ownership was transferred

    return ext;
}
```

Comment: +1 At WWDC 2012, Apple suggested `CFBridgingRelease` rather than `__bridge_transfer`. Also, are you entirely sure you need `CFRelease(extension)` because you've transferred ownership to ARC in the `__bridge_transfer` to `ext`.

Comment: I thought CFBridgingRelease was the same as __bridge_transfer. The docs don't indicate there is any difference. Regardless, I think you are right about not releasing extension due to the transfer. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, if you look at the definition of `CFBridgingRelease`, it just does `__bridge_transfer`, but I assume Apple recommended the new syntax for a reason. I don't know if it's for readability or whether they have some future aspirations for `CFBridgingRelease`. Either is fine, I'm sure, though.

Comment: @Rob Personally I think __bringing_transfer is clearer than CFBridgingRelease. The latter doesn't seem to indicate any transfer of ownership - but that's just my own opinion.

Comment: ATTENTION! Should check uti for being NULL before releasing. Just got myself into this crash trap on a big array of files. So, if (uti != NULL) CFRelease(uti);

Answer (score 16):

Check out [WWDC 2012 - Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405) which outlines new guidelines for Core Foundation objects and ARC. It's about 37:35 into that video. In short, Core Foundation functions with `Copy` or `Create` in the name create an object that has transferred ownership to your app, and your app is responsible for releasing it.

Anyway, if ownership has been transferred via a Core Foundation method with `Copy` or `Create` in the name, you can either release manually it with `CFRelease` when you're done with it, or, easier, you can transfer ownership to ARC and let it take care of it. Historically, to transfer ownership to ARC, we used `__bridge_transfer`, but they now recommend `CFBridgingRelease` (though the latter is just a macro for the former). And, obviously, if you have some Core Foundation object that you retrieved via some other mechanism other than a function with `Copy` or `Create` in the name, you should neither `CFRelease` it nor transfer ownership to ARC.

By way of illustration, this method accomplishes what you want:

```
+ (NSString *) fileExtensionForMimeType:(NSString *)type {

    NSString *uti = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType,
                                                                            (__bridge CFStringRef)type,
                                                                            NULL));

    return CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)uti,
                                                             kUTTagClassFilenameExtension));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In generally speaking, I think you should try to comment the first CFRelease(mimeType) line, and uncomment the followed two lines: CFRelease(uti) and CFRelease(extension). You cast a toll-free bridge to input NSString and ARC will handle the release. But the uti and extension is created/copied as CFString. ARC will not know how to handle them (remember ARC is a compiler feature for NSObject), so you need to CF release them.

Comment: And as @rmaddy said, add a __bridge_transfer on extension to transfer the retain count affair from CF to NSObject.