# Crash caused by calling CFRelease() in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am new to iOS and objc. I have a method written that gives me the tag class `(mime type, file extension etc)` from UTI -

```
- (NSString *)tagForClass:(CFStringRef)tagClass forUTI:(NSString *)UTI {
    CFStringRef UTIRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)(UTI);
    CFStringRef tagRef = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTIRef, tagClass);
    NSString *tag = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(tagRef);
    CFRelease(tagRef);
    return tag;
}
```

This method crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `CFRelease(tagRef);` line. Profiling with `Zombies` tells me that "An `Objective-C` message was sent to a deallocated '`CFString (immutable)`' object (`zombie`) at address: `0x60800023f640`. ￼"

The way I understand this is, I own the `tagRef` as the method which returns that object has the word "copy" in it. So, I am supposed to call `CFRelease()` on it when done.

If I remove the `CFRelease()` line, the program runs fine. But I am afraid I am causing a memory leak in this case.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064386/790842) will help you.

Comment: OK. In the accepted answer in that link, rmaddy says there's no need to release the `extension` object since it is transferred to ARC by casting via `__bridge_transfer`.  So is the CF object `extension` and objc object `ext` the same object on the heap?

Comment: I just verified this. In my own code I posted, `tagRef` and `tag` are the same objects on the heap (they have the same memory address). So calling `CFRelease(tagRef)` was deallocating this heap object and I was then returning a pointer to this deallocated object via `return tag` which caused the crash. Fixed by removing the `CFRelease()` call.

Comment: Yes because `tagRef ` was transferred to ARC, and is been released twice, removing `CFRelease()` should be the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The convention in Core Foundation is that, when the function name contains `Copy` or `Create`, it returns an object with a +1 retain count. When you're done with the object, you must call a release function on it to balance the +1.

When you call `CFBridgingRelease(tagRef)`, that balances the +1. That is why the function has **`Release`** in the name. So you should not also call `CFRelease` on the object. This is the correct code:

```
- (NSString *)tagForClass:(CFStringRef)tagClass forUTI:(NSString *)UTI {
    CFStringRef UTIRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)(UTI);
    CFStringRef tagRef = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTIRef, tagClass);
    // You are now responsible for one release of tagRef.

    NSString *tag = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(tagRef);
    // You have now performed one release of tagRef.

    return tag;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think If your doing `CFRelease()` on already decollated `Object` OR an `Object` with reference count of `0` then the `Object` reference count is already `0`. So you can not release that `Object` that could be issue.

Try to print `Object` reference count using below statement so that you will get idea.

```
NSLog(@"Retain count is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)myObject));
```

Also if your using `ARC` then you don't need to manage `Object` reference count. It will be managed by `ARC`.

Comment: I though the whole point of using ARC was not having to muck around with reference counts :/